# Symbol $p^{0}$ of particle

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, notation

This is a very trivial question, but I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere in a textbook or the internet.

My question is, what particle is represented by this symbol? $$p^{0}$$

Comment: I'm sure the SR chapter in Griffith's E/M defines this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because you both asked for a particle and tagged the question with particle physics, but accepted an answer about something quite different. Did you actually meant the zeroth component of momentum $p^0$ which is the conventional meaning of the symbol you supplied and the answer given below, or did you mean $\rho^0$ the symbol for a particular uncharged, vector meson which is the particle whose symbol most closely resembles the one you supplied and is often misidentified as a roman p?

Comment: I definitely second what dmckee said!!

Comment: I must've mixed up 'rho' with 'p'. I meant momentum 'p', but I also saw 'rho' (as in the uncharged vector meson) represented with the momentum 'p' elsewhere and I wasn't sure if it meant the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that to mean the zeroth component of the [energy-momentum four-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum), for which $p^\mu p_\mu=-m^2$ is an expression of the full version of the famous [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) formula (plus or minus, depending on a sign convention you can choose). $p^\mu p_\mu$ is [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) for, in this case, $p^\mu p_\mu=\frac{1}{c^2}E^2 +p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2$, where $p$ is the usual relativistic momentum.

So, no particle is represented. It can represent the energy of a particle. The energy of a particle is naturally represented as a component of a four component vector, with component $0$ being energy and components $1$ through $3$ being momentum. They can be labeled naturally in this way because of special relativity, which is part of the bread and butter of particle physicists. (Namely: One man's momentum is another man's energy! Time and space can be "rotated" into each other through Lorentz transformations, and as a corollary energy and momentum can be "rotated" into each other through Lorentz transformations.)